# <rich:fileUpload> CSS customization: Don't need '+' symbol in button

Tags: css, jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I am using  in my project and I need to customize the CSS for the same.
Here in the file upload button I want to remove '+' mark(refer in image), How can I do that?.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just overwrite the style, the button class is `rf-fu-btn-cnt-add`, the plus-sign is the background-image.